# How to call controller from ajax and send $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, ajax

I want to call controller from ajax and send POST into database. After POST was sent, i will display database into dropdown list.

but i don't know what to do. here is my code.

ajax script inside view **add_produk.php**

```
<script>
    function getId(val){
        // ajax function
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php base_url();?>index.php/getdata",
            data: "id_kategori="+val,
            success: function(data){
                $("#subcat").html(data);
            }
        });
    }
</script>
```

i want to load controller **getdata.php** and send *$_POST* into this controller, Controller getdata.php :

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');


class Getdata extends CI_Controller
{

    public function index()
    {
        if(!empty($_POST["id_kategori"])){
            $idcat = $_POST["id_kategori"];
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_kategori WHERE id_kategori = $idcat";
            $result = $this->db->query($sql);

            foreach ($result as $subcat) {

                ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $subcat["id_sub_kategori"];?>"><?php echo $city["nama_sub_kategori"];?></option>

                <?php
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

how i can fix my problem?

Comment: Are you able to actually load the file? I would not recommend throwing PHP code inside of your `ajax` script. (`<?php base_url();?>index.php/getdata`) Why not just use forward slash? that's "base url" for most servers

Comment: @Samuel :do u mean `<?php base_url();?>getdata` like this?

Comment: @Samuel :do u have an example code?

Comment: What do you mean man?

Comment: i mean if you have an example code that can solve my problem, you can show me.

Answer (score 0):

i think wrong in here   data: "id_kategori="+val
i dont know php, but u can try "data:{id_kategori:val}"
good luck